# hive query to find number of days in current month

Tags: hive

Could you please help me to write a hive query to find total number of days,number of week days and number of week ends in the current month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add sample data to run query on...

Answer (score 0):

With this something like this you obtain the number of days in the current month:

```
SELECT datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me test it

Comment: I simplified the SQL a little bit：SELECT datediff(add_months("2020-01-01 10:45:30", 1), "2020-01-01 10:45:30")